# Cannot use breakpoints in CLion, Rust ("The breakpoint will not currently be hit" issue)

Tags: debugging, rust, clion, jetbrains-ide

I'm using CLion 2022.2 (fresh install, Windows 11) and the newest version of the Rust plugin.

When I'm trying to run a project, everything works just fine. But when it comes to debugging, it appears that I can't use breakpoints at all. I can place them, but while debugging, all of them are non-active.

When I hover over them, a message pops up that says: "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is associated with this line.". However, it is clear that executable code is present. Example:

[image: code]

The configuration settings is following:

[image: configuration settings]

...and the toolchains settings are here:

[image: toolchains settings]

I've seen a couple of possible solutions, but none of them worked for me. But I believe that the Rust community will help me. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I did a research and simply changed a MinGW (default) environment to Visual Studio environment. VS uses Bundled LLDB version 9.0 and now it seems that problem is gone. But still, what the hell was that? Why I can't use default MinGW + GDB for debugging? And what should I do to fix that?